# Set variable to count of query with another query as source

Tags: sql

I'm getting an incorrect syntax near the word FROM. Can't seem to find anything else like these where a query is retrieving the count of a subquery, any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
SET 
    @ctA = COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         theFN, theIN, theLN, theALY 
     FROM 
         aDT
     GROUP BY 
         theFN, theIN, theLN, theALY
     HAVING 
         theFN = @pF AND theIN = @pI AND theLN = @pL AND theALY = @pLY
    )
```

Comment: Assuming this is for **SQL Server** - then `SET` is not appropriate here, `SET` only initializes a variable to a value, e.g. `SET @ctA = 42`. If you want to run a query and store a result, use `SELECT` instead

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select @ctA = COUNT(*) 
FROM 
(
   SELECT theFN, theIN, theLN, theALY 
   FROM aDT
   GROUP BY theFN, theIN, theLN, theALY
   HAVING theFN = @pF and theIN = @pI 
   and theLN = @pL and theALY = @pLY
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to frame such a query; here's one:

```
 SELECT @ctA = COUNT(*) FROM aDT
           GROUP BY theFN, theIN, theLN, theALY
           HAVING theFN = @pF and theIN = @pI and 
           theLN = @pL and theALY = @pLY
```

... although you might want to filter with a WHERE rather than a HAVING. As it is, the engine has to do all the grouping and then filter; if you use a WHERE clause and then group, it will filter first and then do the grouping.  Fewer records to group on.

ETA:  marc_s made a good point; I have rewritten the query